# power shell does not recognize java

Tags: java

I installed java 12. I type java version in power shell to check whether it installed or not. It gives me:

```
PS C:\Users\17692> java -version
java : The term 'java' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ java -version
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (java:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Power shell does not recognize java.What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Have you added it to your system path?

Comment: You have to add java's `bin` directory to the PATH. Anyway, you should ask this on http://superuser.com

Comment: thank you for your answer. I added it and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you have not set up the environment variable properly. You need to go to the Advanced Settings of Windows and set the Environment variable according to your requirement and need to set that Environment variable to the PATH.

The below guide will help you to set up the JAVA_HOME variable with screenshots.

https://javatutorial.net/set-java-home-windows-10

After going through all the steps I suggest you to reopen the PowerShell.

I hope it helps.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am updating my comment.